# Writing data rom R to AWS Redshift db directly

Tags: r, amazon-redshift

Is there a way to write large datasets from R studio to AWS Redshift db directly? I used the following solution that I got online. but it throws error -unused argument: tablename=".."

```
install.packages('devtools') 
devtools::install_github("RcppCore/Rcpp") 
devtools::install_github("rstats-db/DBI") 
devtools::install_github("rstats-db/RPostgres") 
install.packages("aws.s3", repos = c(getOption("repos"), "http://cloudyr.github.io/drat"))
devtools::install_github("sicarul/redshiftTools")

library("aws.s3") library(RPostgres) library(redshiftTools)

pconn_r <- dbConnect(RPostgres::Postgres(), dbname="db",
                 host='xyz.db.amazon.com', port='1234',
                 user='user', password='pwd',sslmode='require')


rs_replace_table(tst, dbcon=pconn_r, tableName='abc', bucket="pqr")
```

Please help!

Comment: When you call rs_replace_table, should this be table_name rather than tableName?

Comment: Replaced with table_name, it now gives the following error: "Error in parse_aws_s3_response(r, Sig, verbose = verbose) : 
  Forbidden (HTTP 403)."

Answer (score 0):

You can look that library:  [redshift-r](https://github.com/pingles/redshift-r)
Or connect throught RJDBC: [RJDBC](https://www.r-bloggers.com/a-comprehensive-guide-to-connect-r-to-amazon-redshift/)